# What is the added value, if any, of a composite entity in the Microsoft Bot framework regarding a single marked entity

Tags: c#, json, botframework

In tutorial, [Microsoft Bot tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp), a luis service is started that has the ability to deconstruct a sentence about booking a flight.

The entities that are used within the intent utterances have 2 composite entities named To and From which child to a list entity named Airport.

This produces the following json

```
"entities": {
      "From": [
        {
          "Airport": [
            [
              "Berlin"
            ]
          ],
          "$instance": {
            "Airport": [
              {
                "type": "Airport",
                "text": "berlin",
                "startIndex": 19,
                "length": 6,
                "modelTypeId": 5,
                "modelType": "List Entity Extractor",
                "recognitionSources": [
                  "model"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "To": [
        {
          "Airport": [
            [
              "Paris"
            ]
          ],
          "$instance": {
            "Airport": [
              {
                "type": "Airport",
                "text": "paris",
                "startIndex": 29,
                "length": 5,
                "modelTypeId": 5,
                "modelType": "List Entity Extractor",
                "recognitionSources": [
                  "model"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
```

Two things about this seem to be not very efficient but since it is a machine training functionality rather than machine learning I want to know if there is a difference.

1. Why not make Airport the parent and have 2 child entities named ToCity and FromCity? This would allow Airport to be the city with 2 nested objects of ToCity and FromCity if they are extracted in the utterance?
2. Why is a composite used here at all? Is there some added benefit?  With the above abstraction one could simply make 2 simple entities or list entities of ToCity and FromCity I am not seeing why the organization of the composite is befitting here but I may have a miss-understanding.

Here is an example of what I am speaking about regarding question 1.  To me this seems like a better more organized methodology of doing this. But not 100% clear such as is it easier to access or are the score's higher one way or the other.  I will tell you imperically in the below test this methodology produced a higher score for each of the 2 entities.

```
"entities": {
      "Color": [
        {
          "CarColor": [
            "blue"
          ],
          "$instance": {
            "CarColor": [
              {
                "type": "CarColor",
                "text": "blue",
                "startIndex": 6,
                "length": 4,
                "score": 0.9977741,
                "modelTypeId": 1,
                "modelType": "Entity Extractor",
                "recognitionSources": [
                  "model"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "InteriorColor": [
            "red"
          ],
          "$instance": {
            "InteriorColor": [
              {
                "type": "InteriorColor",
                "text": "red",
                "startIndex": 20,
                "length": 3,
                "score": 0.883398235,
                "modelTypeId": 1,
                "modelType": "Entity Extractor",
                "recognitionSources": [
                  "model"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a fair question, however the purpose of the tutorial, and any related example code, is to demonstrate how composite entities can be used. It's true that their usefulness isn't fully realized in this tutorial as there are potentially less complicated ways of achieving the same goal. But, developing an overly complex tutorial would be counter-productive to anyone trying to learn.

Comment: that's understandable. However, can you address the questions in the particulars. I understand why completely but I am wondering the why so I can correctly build my models.